# ValueError: No tables found by using pd.read_html

Tags: python, pandas

cannot download the table even thought HTML shows there is a table, any way to fix it ?
the code is ok when I change other website link, not sure what is wrong with this website~

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import datetime
import os

url = "https://www.cmoney.tw/etf/e210.aspx?key=0050"
response = requests.get(url)
listed = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
listed.columns = listed.iloc[0,:]
listed = listed[["標的代號","標的名稱"]]
listed = listed.iloc[1:]
listed
```

---

ValueError: No tables found

Comment: which line of the above snippet do you get this error?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-97d4e8b702f3> in <module>
      7 url = "https://www.cmoney.tw/etf/e210.aspx?key=0050"
      8 response = requests.get(url)
----> 9 listed = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
     10 listed.columns = listed.iloc[0,:]
     11 listed = listed[["標的代號","標的名稱"]]

Comment: It's not possible to get table with `read_table` because the table is loaded dynamically in javascript in `<div class="tb-out" grp="tableOutsideBlock"></div>`. You have to use selenium before.